# How to make changes to existing C# code when only dll's are available

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have an ASP.NET project that is in production that I have inherited. The original development company did not release the project/solution files for the site. The only code I have available is what is running on the server where all of the C# code is wrapped up in a few .dll files. I have created a new web project and included all of the available files in Visual Studio 2013. I have read I can decompile the dll's using reflector and I have been able to do that and see the decompiled code. How do I add the decompiled code into the project so I can begin to make changes to the classes? Or am I missing something obvious that will make this easier?

Comment: So, your question is "How do I add the code into the project ?" ... oO

Comment: Yes, I need to add the code to the project so I can make the requested changes and re-deploy the site to the server.

Comment: use ILSpy or reflexil....Your best bet is to recreate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the code is available only in the .dll files, please don't try to modify the existing c# code. Instead you can use "C# Extension Method" option to add your new functionality by extending the available class. This is the most preferred way to add new code to the existing classes.

You can find more on C# extension methods on below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx